# Extracting template arguments' value

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename... TT>
class List
{
public:
    typedef T head;
    typedef List<TT...> next;
    enum { size = sizeof...(TT)+1 };
};
```

and this main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

template <int T>
struct Int {
    enum { value = T };
};

int main() {
    typedef List<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>> list;
    cout << list::template head.value << endl; // Error
    cout << list::size; // Works
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
     cout << list::template head.value << endl;
```

I would appreciate any help.. I've been trying to solve this for the past half hour and this is probably something very stupid that I just can't put my finger on.

Comment: For readability, consider using [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead of `typedef`, and if you are on C++17, `static constexpr std::size_t` instead of `enum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` is a type. That means that you can't disambiguate it with `template`, nor can you access it with `.`. There's not much to do to fix it:

```
std::cout << list::head::value << std::endl;
```

Also, please get rid of the `using namespace std;`.